# Does the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(\frac{e}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n})^n$ converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Does the series 
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}(\frac{e}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n})^n$$
converge?

Comment: Hint: $e>(1+1/n)^n$.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It holds $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{e}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^n}\right)^n = \sqrt{e} \not= 0$$ so the series diverges necessarily.

Comment: Can you justify that limit ?

Comment: So you downvoted because you cannot calculate it yourself?

Comment: @Yves Daoust.For $n>1$ we have $n\log (1+n^{-1})=n(1-n^{-2}/2+n^{-3}/3-...)=$ $1-n^{-1}/2+n^{-2}/3.$......  So $e/(1+1/n)^n=$ $ \exp (1/2n)\cdot \exp (O(1/n^2))$  as $n\to \infty.$.....  So $[e/(1+1/n)^n]^n= $ $\sqrt e\cdot \exp (O(1/n))$ $ \to \sqrt e$...... Similarly, using  $\log [(1+n^{-1})^{n+1}]=$ $\log [ (1-(n+1)^{-1})^{n+1}]$ we obtain  $ [e/(1+n^{-1})^{n+1}]]^n \to 1/\sqrt e.$

Comment: @Gono: I downvoted because computing this limit is harder than the original question and it will not help the OP.

Comment: "So you downvoted because you cannot calculate it yourself?" @Gono FYI, this might be viewed as the worst possible reaction to Yves' comment.

Answer (score 3):

For $x>0$ we have $$\log (1+x)=\int_1^{1+x} (1/y)\;dy<\int_1^{1+x}1\;dy =x.$$ So $\log ((1+1/n)^n)=n\log (1+1/n)<n(1/n)=1.$ So $(1+1/n)^n<e$. So each term in the series is greater than $1.$